# Why does my Eclipse launch config ignore my plug-in's environment specification?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

In my big project, I have an Eclipse Application launch config. It launches the application based on selected features (features being groups of plug-ins).

In one of these features, there is a plug-in which is specified to only be installed if it is launched in a Linux environment. This is what that looks like in the `feature.xml` file:

```xml
<plugin
    id="com.company.package.cool.plugin"
    os="linux"
    ws="gtk"
    arch="x86_64"
    download-size="0"
    install-size="0"
    version="0.0.0"
    unpack="false"/>
```

And yet, Eclipse installs the plug-in when the application is launched in a Windows environment.

Why does Eclipse ignore its own specification? Is there a fix? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Eclipse-PlatformFilter` in the plug-in's MANIFEST.MF controls when the plug-in is "resolved". Convert your plug-in to a fragment an add this line (macOS only example):

```
Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.ws=cocoa) (osgi.os=macosx) (osgi.arch=x86_64) )
```

I'm not absolutely sure but I think the feature.xml specification is only used by installers.

More info can be found on [vogel/a](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFragmentProject/article.html)

Comment: This... kinda worked. Launching the application gives me a warning that "Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.ws=gtk) (osgi.os=linux) (osgi.arch=x86_64) )" for the plug-in in question. If I continue launching, a `BundleException` is thrown because the plug-in could not be resolved.

Comment: If you use this on a normal plugin you can't use `Require-Bundle` in other plug-ins to refer to it because it may be unresolved. Normally you just specify it on a Fragment [see here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFragmentProject/article.html)

Comment: The plug-in is not referred to using `Require-Bundle` by any other plug-in. What do you mean by "normally you just specify it on a fragment"?

Comment: You have a normal plug-in without a platform filter and a fragment of that plug-in which has the filter. For example SWT has `org.eclipse.swt` normal plug-in and a fragment for each OS `org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64` for example. Since the main plug-in is always present you don't get missing plug-in errors.

Comment: I remade my linux-specific plug-in into a fragment, but it did not help. During Validation, Eclipse detects that I'm not running linux and says this as a problem "Platform filter did not match".

Comment: That is expected, it is not an error. It is just telling you that fragment won't actually be used for this run configuration